# how to bring abstraction in java application..logic for abstraction in project

Tags: java, interface, abstract

I know abstract classes and interfaces in java but I want to know how to bring abstraction in working software/project? how to thing in such way which brings abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is vague at best, however the usage of interfaces helps abstraction because you are not working with concrete types. For instance:

```
IPrinter p = PrinterFactory.getPrinter(conditions);
...
p.print(content);
```

In the below line, you are not aware of exactly *what* printer you are using. Since you are just *using* the logic, you do not really care. All that you care about is that the factory will give you the printer you are after and that the `print` method will print the content to the right stream.

If you want to change the printer being used, you make the amendments in the factory class so that you get a different `IPrinter` implementation which does what you need (which in this case it would be to print to some other media). This would mean that you have essentially changed the outcome of a piece of code without changing much of it.